# Show that a particular force field with $\operatorname{curl} = 0$ is not conservative

Tags: vector-fields, line-integrals

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$Show that the force field
$$
-Q\, \Vec{i} + P\, \Vec{j} = -\frac{y}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\, \Vec{i} + \frac{x}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\, \Vec{j}
$$
is not conservative, even though it satisfies the condition
$$
\frac{\dd P}{\dd x} = \frac{\dd Q}{\dd y} = \frac{(-x^{2} + y^{2})}{(x^{2} + y^{2})^{2}}.
$$

Comment: Note that there’s a hole in the domain. Look around that for problems.

Answer (score 4):

If $\vec F$ is your field and $\gamma$ is the unit circle centered at zero, then $$  \int_\gamma \vec F \cdot d\vec r=2\pi\neq 0  $$ so that   $\vec F$ is not conservative.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I was hoping there would be a similar way like the condition I have written in the OP. A second test if you'd like. If you have a very complicated formula it first requires you to actually understand that you have a hole somewhere in your domain (Maybe very rarely will it ever be at other points than (0,0), but let's say say you have a hole at (3,4) randomly for some reason). It requires you to go around that point, to prove it, and at least for me without starting to graph stuff that would be very complicated.